# Probability of losing everything in N games

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-walk

Consider a gambler who starts with an initial amount of money of $£i$, obtain $£R$ with probability $p$ and lose $£J$ with probability $q=1-p$. What is the probability that it loses everything if he plays maximum $N$ times?

Comment: You can probably solving this as a version of the [Gambler's Ruin](http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/FE-Notes/4700-07-Notes-GR.pdf) problem.